# Sockets de java, se pueden tener al mismo tiempo DataInputStream y ObjetcInputStrem en un socket cliente?

Tags: java, socket

me esta pasando una cosilla que no entiendo. Estoy haciendo una pequeña aplicación, para practicar, con sockets en java. Dicha aplicación tiene que intercambiar entre el cliente y servidor datos simples (un entero, una cadena, etc) y también objetos. Para el tema de los mensajes pues sin problema, pero cuando me he querido poner a intercambiar objetos se me queda colgado el cliente a la hora de crearlos. Os pongo este código:

```
                // Para mensajes
            this.dis = new DataInputStream(this.socketCliente.getInputStream());
            this.dos = new DataOutputStream(this.socketCliente.getOutputStream());

            // Para Informacion
            this.ois = new ObjectInputStream(this.socketCliente.getInputStream());
            this.oos = new ObjectOutputStream(this.socketCliente.getOutputStream());
```

Si elimino las dos ultimas líneas, todo va bien, si las incluyo el cliente se cuelga al llegar ahí, la pregunta es sencilla: Puedo tener mas de un stream en un socket? Yo por ese socket quiero mandar tanto mensajes simples como objetos, pero no puedo crear los streams para objetos, porque al poner la dos líneas última se me queda colgado el cliente.

Espero haberme explicado.
un cordial saludo

Comment: Agrega el error que se produce.

Comment: El error es que se queda colgada la aplicación, no es que me muestre un error en sí. Si quito las dos últimas líneas la aplicación funciona, si las pongo, se queda colgado.

Comment: Si no hay ningún error visible está difícil encontrar el problema. Solo con el código que proporcionas te puedo decir que debe funcionar, ya lo probé. Podrías agregar el resto del código para poder reproducir el error.